# force textview to show numbers with only english digits

Tags: android, textview, locale

I use below code to force my textview to show its text numbers with English digits:

```
txtScale.setText("x" + String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, String.valueOf(scaleValue)));
```

but it is not working and keep showing the numbers with selected locale. If application locale set to Arabic, it show numbers to Arabic, if set to English it show them English but I want to force to show numbers in English at all states.

For example I want to show below text in Arabic:

```
۱۲۳۴ //are one two three four
```

As:

```
1234
```

If it helps, I use below code for changing the language of the app manually:

```
    Locale locale = new Locale(CurrentLanguage);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: can you explain clearly what do you mean by show in English? showing 1 as "one"? maybe add an examlpe

Answer (score 4):

Not very sure what you need, but I guess you need this:

```
txtScale.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "x%d", scaleValue));
```

`String.valueOf(scaleValue)` there error was here, where you have converted the number based on default Locale

Comment: please see my edit for more details about what I want. I change my code like what you sent but still showing numbers with arabic digits.

Comment: what is scaleValue? is it a long or int?

Comment: it is an int variable

Comment: Can you check if you copied the code correctly? or you can try this
`String.format(new Locale("en"), "x%d", 123)`, I have tested and I can switch the text probably like this `String.format(new Locale("ar"), "x%d", 123)`

Comment: Did you accidentally copied the code from the answer above instead?

Comment: no I checked an it is the correct code. There is something strange. When I set language to "en" and use String.format(new Locale("ar","x%d",scaleValue) it is showing numbers by arabic digits (I mean the code working) but when I set language to Arabic and use the code with "en" it is not showing numbers with english digits

Comment: um, this sounds really strange, you may try this, see if it has some magic `NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format(scaleValue)`

Comment: no changes. I think it is not related to the formatting. I think there would be some problems with setting the text to the textview. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't believe setText would change your String, you can verify that by putting Log and output your string

Comment: the output of the string on the watcher is with english numbers but what I see in screen is with arabic digits

Comment: you may want to test your code in emulator, maybe it is the Locale in your device which has a special bug. also you may want to try `new Locale("en", "us")`

Comment: I tried new Locale("zh") too for only testing the code with other locale. It is not workig too but new Locale("ar") working. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried new Locale("en", "us")? I am guessing it may need full locale, or it always fallback to arabic, while Locale.English has language code only.

Comment: Yes I tried new Locale("en","us") too. Also it always do not use arabic. When I set the languge to "en" and do not change the locale with new Locale("ar") to arabic, it shows english digits

Comment: Really run out of idea now, could be related to the code you just posted, if you can replicate the problem in emulator, then you may want to upload a sample project with the problem to github, difficult to remote debug for this.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem, the solution was to concatenate the number variable with an empty string.
For example like this :

```
public void displayPoints(){
    TextView scoreA = findViewById(R.id.score_id);
    scoreA.setText(""+points);
}
```

I used this

```
scoreA.setText(""+points);
```

instead of this

```
scoreA.setText(String.format("%d",points));
```

this will even give you a warning that hardcoded text can not be properly translated to other languages, which exactly what we want here :) .

Comment: The Concatenation does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem is also with the locale of the TextView. In API level 17 or after, it is possible to individually set locale of the TextView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextLocale(java.util.Locale)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and it was fixed by using:

```
 public static String nFormate(double d) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    String st= nf.format(d);
    return st;
}
```

The string value could be viewed without problems.

Answer (score 1):

with set font you can achieve this, but to convert non-english digits to English digits I use `Long.parseLong("۱۰۰۰")` or `Integer.parseInt("۱۰۰۰")` that the output will be `1000`.

But note that `Double.parseDouble("۱۰۰۰")` will return same ۱۰۰۰